# VBA: Call event listener on <head> element?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to call the keydown method for a site to submit my text entry as I do not want to SendKeys. The keydown method is attached to the top element of html, labeled . How do I reference the head and how do I call it's keydown method with the "enter" key value?

[image: Event Listeners for Head element]

---

Addendum: Does this help at all?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct however you can look into creating an html keydown event, attaching it to the appropriate node and dispatching it. For your other question.... `ie.document.head`

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try that when I get in next

Comment: What would be the appropriate node? I dispatched a "keydown" event on both the head and the document itself, but neither worked. I think the head is the right node as it seems to have the keydown event, but I can't seem to trigger it